# Strange string issue

Tags: powershell

I have a very strange issue that is hard to describe, so please bear with me.

I have the variable $BestHost that just contains the name of a windows server. I am passing this variable to a module that I have written called Get-CurrentSite which does some tests to check which physical location a server is in.

In testing, I manually set

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Besthost = "WK-VPS-009"

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CurrentSite -CHost $Besthost
WK
```

and the module calls fine, giving the desired result. The server is in site WK.

In the larger script, $BestHost is defined by an API call, but the result is the same. it reads

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $BestHost = ($BestHost = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://hypervision.host.net/api/v1/vps/best_host?exclude=$currentsiteswap,$VPShost").Content

   $BestHost= $BestHost -replace '"',"" #this just removes additional "

PS C:\Windows\system32> $BestHost
WK-VPS-009
```

but when I try to use this variable with Get-CurrentSite this time, I get the error

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CurrentSite -CHost $BestHost
Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.
At C:\Users\frank\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Get-CurrentSite\Get-CurrentSite.psm1:10 char:12
+ $HostAdd = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $CHost { get-NetIPAddress}
```

Which is an error from the Invoke-Command, the first thing I use Get-CurrentSite to determine the site location.

My first thought was the variable type so...

This is the variable when set manually:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $BestHost.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                    
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                    
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

and this is set by the API call:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $BestHost.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                    
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                    
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

To me they look to be identical variables containing exactly the same data, one works, one doesn't. I am perplexed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Further information

I just placed these 2 results into 2 different variables and compared them and got the following

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $BestHost
WK-VPS-009

PS C:\Windows\system32> $BestHost1
WK-VPS-009
PS C:\Windows\system32> $BestHost1.Equals($BestHost)
False

PS C:\Windows\system32> ($BestHost.GetEnumerator() | % ToInt32 $null | % ToString X4) -join '-'
0057-004B-002D-0056-0050-0053-002D-0030-0030-0039

PS C:\Windows\system32> ($BestHost1.GetEnumerator() | % ToInt32 $null | % ToString X4) -join '-'
0057-004B-002D-0056-0050-0053-002D-0030-0030-0039-000A-000A
```

Comment: Compare `($BestHost.GetEnumerator() | % ToInt32 $null | % ToString X4) -join '-'` in both cases.

Comment: OK, I will try that, I have added some info to the end of the main question which may also help

Comment: `$BestHost1` does have two extra newline characters in it. It should be fine if you `.Trim()` them.

Comment: Did the trim and they are still slightly different, and it still gets the same error.

Comment: Actually, I did something really stupid. the trim worked perfectly. Thank you. Can we just clarify what wass happened here so I can fully understand? There were special charicters in the string that I couldn't see, and by enumerating the characters I was able to see them, then remove them?

Comment: *There were special charicters in the string that I couldn't see, and by enumerating the characters I was able to see them, then remove them?* Yes, them are called [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Comment: `$BestHost = $BestHost -replace '[\s"]*', ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your API function somehow adds two linefeeds to the string output (000A) 
Before processing it, clean up these linefeeds by adding the following to your code:

```
  $besthost = $besthost -Replace '\x0A',''
```

You can combine the action with the cleanup of the double quotes (" , ascii code x22 ), by using a regular expression (regexp):

```
 $besthost = $besthost -Replace '[\x0A\x22]',''
```